# use of multiple languages in visual studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

in visual studio we can develop applications using multiple programming languages such as C#, C++, Visual Basic. Is this due to CLR?

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is.

> The functionality of .Net Framework
>   supporting many programming languages
>   is due to the use of the powerful CLR

See this link:

http://www.dotnet-guide.com/

- The above statement can be found in the 3rd paragraph beneath the "Click here for FREE subscription" button.

Comment: But c++ in vs compiles not only in cli but into binary too.

Answer (score 2):

Mainly, but I guess it is also a trend for IDEs to support several languages (vs one IDE per language). Eclipse for example supports [20 languages](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t71848.rhtml).

Answer (score 1):

The fact that multiple .NET languages share a runtime and BCL, and can talk to each-other very easily is due to the CLR/CLI, but ultimately the VS IDE *doesn't* just write CLI (unmanaged C++ being the obvious example). Simply, the IDE (like many others) is designed to be extensible.

If you wanted, I'm very sure it would be possible to write your *own* compiler plugin for VS, using a managed or unmanaged language.

Comment: sir, you mean that it is due to CLR that we can develop applications in any language in VS.

Comment: sir, also when i use C, in TurboC, then is there any role of Framework, or Runtime or BCL or CLI?

Comment: @sqlchild - I'm pretty sure I said the exact opposite: it is due to VS that we can develop applications in any language in VS. The CLI merely makes it convenient.

Comment: @sqlchild - for C++ (unmanaged) you might compare STL; but C? less so

Comment: I would even further clarify with "The CLI makes it possible for those languages to interact and/or replace eachother. TO the point even where it doesn't matter which one you use. It's all the same IL.". In theory anyway.